# Rmarkdown with no X11

Tags: r, linux, unix, r-markdown, x11

I'm trying to run an `Rmarkdown` script (`myRmdScript.Rmd`) on a `linux` machine with no `X11` enabled and crashing with:

```
Quitting from lines 2-7 (myRmdScript.Rmd)
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
  unable to start device PNG
Calls: <Anonymous> ... block_exec -> chunk_device -> dev_new -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grDevices::png(f) : unable to open connection to X11 display ''
2: In (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''

Execution halted
```

This is my first code chunk:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(Cairo)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev="CairoPNG")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE,out.width='2000px',dpi=200)
```
````

Is there anyway to solve this other than enabling `X11` on this machine (which is unfavorable to RAM consumption issues)?

Comment: Put `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev="CairoPNG")` at the top of the Rmd and install the `Cairo` pkg if not installed and give it a go.

Comment: Are you sure this means X11 will not be required?

Comment: `Cairo` pkg proper shld not require it, but — then again — neither shld base R anymore. `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` output wld help know versions of things on your end. Also <https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots> (skip down to `dev`) has all the output format options. I'd try various bitmap ones if you are still having issues.

Comment: The error persists despite having knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev="CairoPNG") at the top of the Rmd

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need recently. The proposed solution by @hrbmstr in the comment is close but won't work.

The missing part is that you should also add dev="CairoPNG" into the setup chunk, otherwise the setup chunk won't run.

My server capabilities, note that jpeg, png, cairo, x11 tiff are FALSE:

```
> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Full Rmd that compiles with Cairo package. Note the dev parameter in the setup chunk.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "TC"
date: "12/20/2019"
output: 
    html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, dev="CairoPNG"}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, dev="CairoPNG")
```

# test figure

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[Original discussion](https://d.cosx.org/d/421127-x11-rmd)